# Matlab call function in same package

Tags: matlab

It there an easy way to call to access a class in the same package without specifying the package name.

Example

I have a package name foo with the classes bar and bar2, lets say I want bar2 to be a subclass of bar, I will then write

classdef bar2 < foo.bar

Is there a way were I can tell matlab that it should look in the same package.

The reason I want that is if I change the package name to fo I would have to change it in all files within the package.

Comment: There is no good solution. Use package names which are never used for anything else, then you can use search&replace to rename a package with minimal effort.

Comment: Ok, thanks. There will also be some search and replace in the files which uses the package. So in the end will the extra work not be that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Matlab documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-subclasses--syntax-and-techniques.html?refresh=true) explicitly says that you need to include the package name when subclassing (even if you are in the same package).

> **Referencing Superclasses Contained in Packages**
>
> If a superclass is contained in a package, include the package name. For example:
>
> ```
>   classdef stock < financial.asset
>      methods
>         function s = stock(asset_args,...)
>            if nargin == 0
>               ...
>            end
>            % Call asset constructor
>            s@financial.asset(asset_args); 
>            ...
>         end
>      end
>   end
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I believe there is no way to do this. Yes, it's annoying.